# How do I set the default sound card in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: sound, alsa

Using "alsamixer" in the terminal, one can select a sound card. However, even if one tries to save settings with "sudo alsactl store" after a power cycle the sound card returns to its previous default and resets its state (any modifications you made to sound settings of that card). I need to switch my default sound card from sound card 0 to sound card 1, and get sound card 1 to save the changes I made to its dB settings. Any assistance?

Comment: The card selection in alsamixer just affects what mixer controls are shown in alsamixer. And doesn't Ubuntu use PulseAudio (i.e., pavucontrol)?

Comment: Test for pulseaudio with `pactl list`. If this works, follow the guidelines for changing pulseaudio defaults.